# SQLITE Select query with ? Fails to print

Tags: c++, sqlite

Iam Encountering a Problem where prepared statements and Binding values works Good For Insert statements but not For Select Statements ....
here is the piece of code

```
 int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
 sqlite3 *db; // sqlite3 db struct
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  char *szSQL;
  int rc;

  // Open the test.db file
   rc = sqlite3_open("test32.db", &db);

   if( rc )
   {
     // failed
     fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", 
          sqlite3_errmsg(db));
   }
    else
  {
// success
fprintf(stderr, "Open database successfully\n");
 }

  // create myTable
 //szSQL = "create table myTable1011 (FirstName varchar(30), LastName varchar(30), Age smallint not null);";

   // rc = sqlite3_exec(db, szSQL, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

   // if( rc == SQLITE_OK )
    // {
   //insert 1 record into myTable
    // RunInsertParamSQL(db, "asyb", "com", 42);




// fetch records

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *pzTest;

 //Doesnt WORK 

szSQL = "select * from myTable1011 where age = ?";

 rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, szSQL, strlen(szSQL), &stmt, &pzTest);

if( rc == SQLITE_OK ) 

  // bind the value 

  int test = 42;

sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, test);//Doesnt work if i give 42 directly instead if test in bind statement

// commit 
 sqlite3_step(stmt);
 sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}


 // rc = sqlite3_exec(db, szSQL, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);


// Close test.db file
 sqlite3_close(db);

 getchar();

  return 0;
}

// Insert rec
//WORKS WELL
void RunInsertParamSQL(sqlite3 *db, char *fn, char *ln, int age)
{
  if (!db)
    return;

  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  const char *pzTest;
  char *szSQL;

  // Insert data item into myTable
 szSQL = "insert into myTable1011 (FirstName, LastName, Age) values (?,?,?);";

  int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, szSQL, strlen(szSQL), &stmt, &pzTest);

  if( rc == SQLITE_OK ) {
   // bind the value 
     sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, fn, strlen(fn), 0);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, ln, strlen(ln), 0);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, age);

    // commit 
     sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  }
}
```

Iam getting No output except Open database successfully

But if i give
      szSQL = "select * from myTable1011";
       rc = sqlite3_exec(db, szSQL, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
       //I get the whole table ....

How do i Print Selectively ??
and Why does my Where Condition Fails ?????

Comment: Unrelated, but if the `sqlite3_open` call fails, should you really continue the program?

Comment: Related to your problem, have you checked the return codes of the bind function? Or the step call? Or the finalize call?

Comment: ya they are fine;; 
(http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)
it works for insert operation ;;
then why not for select too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it....

If you use Sprintf instead of Prepare/Bind Statements Iam able to get an Output ....

```
sprintf(szSQL,"select * from Foldersonly WHERE Foldersonly.FolderName = \"%s\" ",Root_Path);
sqlite3_exec(db, szSQL, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

this will work ...

Answer (score 0):

There is not output because the code does not even try to output anything.

You have to read the column values with the [sqlite3_column_* functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.htm):

```
...
for (;;) {
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_ROW)
        break;
    // this depends on what columns you actually have:
    int         first_column  = sqlite3_column_int (stmt, 0);
    const char *second_column = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
    ...
    printf("ID: %d, name: %s\n", first_column, second_column);
}
if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
    printf("error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
...
```

Comment: i can get this output with Select * from table ...
do i get one particular column which matches a condition ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been in a similar situation, but not quite the same.  I'll describe what I saw and what I fixed, in case others have the same issue:

I had an existing SQLite3 database file that I wanted to query, so I didn't try any INSERT statements, but just the basic `select * from sqlite_master where type='table'` - but I got no output whatever (similar to the OP, I think).

In my case it was a very simple mistake on my part - when opening the database file I read the location from a config file, where I forgot to mention the subdirectory, so the file did not exist in that location.  The point is, that the `sqlite3_open()` statement that I used to open the database file returned success, so I thought it had opened the file correctly, but what it actually did was to quite happily create a new empty database file.  This had no tables to display, so it correctly displayed nothing.

I now find in [the documentation for sqlite3_open](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) that I could use `sqlite3_open_v2()`, which allows me to specify one of: `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY`, `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` or `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`. The first two flags return an error if the database file does not already exist, and the third flag combination creates the file if it does not already exist and is "the behavior that is always used for `sqlite3_open()`...".  Using this would have helped me identify the problem much sooner :-)